# Camel CXF throwing Timeout response in my rest API (Producer)

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I am exposing a Rest API and my consumer wants me to throw a timeout response when my API took more than X seconds. One way I think is take the start time and end time and throw an error. Is there an efficient way?

```
I know that below timeout works for the consumers. I need something like this for my API.
    <http-conf:conduit  name="*.http-conduit">
        <http-conf:client ReceiveTimeout="5000"/>
    </http-conf:conduit>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Why doesn't your consumer call your API with a timeout?